# reading in an xml file and using the data for a label

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am using visual studio 2010 to create a windows form for reading in data from an xml file and displaying it in a form. any code relating to dynamically changing the content of a label or textbox with this information would be much appreciated. At the moment i can read in an xml file and display some content in the console.

thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get a good response to your question you should include some source code and a specific example. As it stands, this question is too vague to get good feedback

Answer (score 1):

Once you've loaded your Xml, all you need to do is set the `.Text` property of a TextBox or Label control:

```
string xmlData = "<xml>\r\n<tag>This is my xml</tag></xml";
myTextBox.Text = xmlData;
```

You said you can get Xml content to display in the console, you'll just be directing the output to a WinForm control, rather than the console. Also, if you use a `TextBox`, you'll want to set it's [`Multiline` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to `true`.

You can read more about [TextBox controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Label controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parser to extract elements

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

then use control properties 
    textBox.text = someString